# Custom Chapter Header in Thesis

Tags: header-footer, chapters

Currently my chapter headers look like this:

[image]

How to make it look like this:
[image]

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX! Please read [this article](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb38-3/tb120duck.pdf) to get used to how to ask questions here. We need to know what your working environment is. Please post an MWE.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility with package `titlesec`. There remains a problem : how to format chapter headers for unumbered chapter?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath} 

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
 \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries}{\Large\chaptername~\thechapter\endgraf\titlerule[1pt]}{-3ex}{\LARGE\filleft}%

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]